# CPP_Magic IF_ELSE Macro?

Tags: c, macros

[cpp_magic](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic) extends what can typically be done with the C Preprocessor.
(It's a single header file and is on GitHub, [here](https://github.com/18sg/uSHET/blob/master/lib/cpp_magic.h).)

The `IF_ELSE(cond)(<true_result>, <false_result>)` is a super useful macro!

### How can expressions be evaluated in the `cond` clause?

It doesn't appear to work as advertised: with expressions in the `cond` part.

The following returns 10:

```
int greater = IF_ELSE(10 > 20)(10, 20);
```

The macro always returns the first argument, unless it is a simple 0 or 1.

Is the `c` argument (*condition*) a misnomer (and is really ust a simple *value*)?

I also tried this, according to a suggestion below, but it gives the same result:

```
#define GREATER(x,y) BOOL(x > y)
int greater = IF_ELSE(GREATER(10,20))(10, 20);
```

But it also evaluates to `10`.

(Note that IF_ELSE already calls BOOL(c) on its argument.)

### Has anyone used IF_ELSE with a general preprocessor expression?

Comment: The C preprocessor only evaluates expressions in `#if` statements. It can't do it when expanding a macro.

Comment: Maybe `IF_ELSE(BOOL(10 > 20))(10)(20)` Note also that `IF_ELSE` takes the two results as separate parenthesized lists, not a comma-separated list.

Comment: See the description of how all this works at http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic

Comment: @Barmar Macros expansion cannot evaluate expressions.  `BOOL` doesn't magically change this; all it does is apply a C preprocessor pattern matcher to the three tokens `10`, `>`, and `20`.  You could roll a comparison macro that would perform the *math*, but you basically have to implement the math yourself using macros... and it would look like `BOOL(GREATER(10,20))`.

Comment: @HWalters I suspected so. The code in the web page is hard to follow, it's really wizardly stuff!

Comment: Maybe later... before I actually submit it as an answer I would have to verify it's in cpp_magic, which I have yet to even get much less look at (I was only speaking of a hypothetical greater... but I'm glad it worked for you!)

Comment: @HWalters GREATER is not in cpp_magic - I just created it before calling it like this #define GREATER(x,y) BOOL(x > y). But I spoke too soon, since: IF_ELSE(GREATER(10,20))(10, 20);` evaluates to `10`. So IF_ELSE just returns the first argument again.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your comment. Yes, this is being expanded *as* a macro -- it does not need to appear within another macro, as IF_ELSE *is* the macro. 
I added a link to the header on GitHub so you can see that it is a bit odd, but the true_result and false_result parts are given as a 2-argument list.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? `IF_ELSE` doesn't seem "super useful" to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at cpp_magic, it looks a bit basic.  If you want to evaluate math in the preprocessor using that, you have to basically implement the math yourself using macros.  First off the bat, cpp_magic's `IF_ELSE` macro is defined as follows:

```
#define IF_ELSE(condition) _IF_ ## condition
```

That's a dead stop to using it as you prescribe, because this macro's expansion list contains a paste.  The way macros expand involves four steps:

- Argument substitution (a.s.; 6.10.3.1), where for each mention of a *parameter* in the macro's replacement list where said parameter is not participating in a paste or stringification, the corresponding *argument* is fully expanded, and the resulting expansion replaces the mention in the replacement list.
- Stringification (6.10.3.2)
- Pasting (6.10.3.3)
- Rescan-and-further-replacement (r.a.s.r.; 6.10.3.4), where the resulting replacement list is rescanned; during this rescan the macro in question is marked as invalid for further expansion ("painted blue") to avoid recursion.

So in cpp_magic's implementation of `IF_ELSE`, no matter what you pass in as the condition, it will not do a.s.; instead, it will simply paste to `_IF_`.  E.g., if you call `IF_ELSE(BOOL(x))`, you would simply get `_IF_BOOL(x)`.  You can patch this (but it's ugly, and there's a much much better library... see below) by adding an indirection macro like this:

```
#define EVAL_IF_ELSE(condition) IF_ELSE(condition)
```

...so you need at least this.  For a greater comparision, you would need to implement greater.  Here's a trivial implementation:

```
#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_I(A,B)
#define GLUE_I(A,B) A##B
// repeats X N times
#define N_TIMES(N,X) GLUE(N_TIMES_,N)(X)
#define N_TIMES_1(X) X
#define N_TIMES_2(X) X,N_TIMES_1(X)
#define N_TIMES_3(X) X,N_TIMES_2(X)
#define N_TIMES_4(X) X,N_TIMES_3(X)
#define N_TIMES_5(X) X,N_TIMES_4(X)
// pop; technically non-compliant for one parameter
// which I could code around, but this is a simplified
// demo only (and there's a much better way)
#define POP(...) POP_I(__VA_ARGS__)
#define POP_I(X,...) __VA_ARGS__
#define NTH(N,...) GLUE(NTH_,N)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NTH_1(...) NTH_1_I(__VA_ARGS__,)
#define NTH_1_I(X,...) X
#define NTH_2(X,...) NTH_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NTH_3(X,...) NTH_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NTH_4(X,...) NTH_3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NTH_5(X,...) NTH_4(__VA_ARGS__)
#define COMPARE(X,Y) NTH(X,POP(N_TIMES(Y,L)),E,N_TIMES(5,G))
#define GREATER(X,Y) GLUE(GREATER_RESULT_,COMPARE(X,Y))
#define GREATER_RESULT_L 0
#define GREATER_RESULT_E 0
#define GREATER_RESULT_G 1
```

...so that's a nice *start*.  And this greater works perfectly... for numbers up to 5... so long as you ignore the 1 case.  There's a skeleton here for how to do other comparisons, but they would only work up to 5.  A demo working up to 20 is shown [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3810ae62eb86d36).

This shows what you want to do is *possible*, but it's still a lot of work.  Here I'm only showing a way to do a comparison; but everything else you want to do (add, sub, mul, div, etc) also needs an implementation, and each piece is code.  If you want to play with it, knock yourself out, but I would recommend for play ditching the C language and just use your preprocessor like I do in the demo.

**There is a much, much better way**

...and that is to let someone else do all of the work for you.  And they have!  What you're in effect trying to do has been pulled into the boost preprocessor library.  BPP also has add, sub, mul, div, and so on.  For BPP's implementation, the saturation is at 255.  Here's how you would do your conditional using boost preprocessor:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/comparison.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control.hpp>
BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_GREATER(10,20),10,20)
```

...and a [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a52f6cc1d5b06b2)

Comment: Thoughtful, thorough, and even includes a better way!
... of course the final answer would be `Boost`  ;->

Comment: This is for a microcontroller with extremely limited resources at runtime. Can the Boost BPP solution be used without C++ and run-time support?

Comment: Note that ccp_magic uses only 2 args (not 3): `IF_ELSE(cond)(t, f)`

Comment: Boost preprocessor as the name suggests is a preprocessor only library, so yes it will work without C++ (C/C++ share the same preprocessor).  If you note in my examples, I'm driving it with gcc not g++ (use of coliru's convenient because they have boost pp right there); but I'm also only running the preprocessor (-E).